# Divs are not positioned correctly with margin

Tags: html, css

I have self-made progressbar with some steps along the way. However, for some reason, my divs, text_div, are moved about 2 pixels to the right for every element. I don't understand what is causing this as I have margin, padding and border set to 0.

I'm sorry for the confusing description but I think it will be clear to you when you see it yourselves. Try change the width of the bordered div to 100px, 200px, 300px. Every text_div seems to be off about 2px for some reason.

http://jsfiddle.net/xjL6f/1/

```
.text_div
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually to do with the combination of whitespace and `display:inline-block`

See this [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ChubbyNinja/xjL6f/2/) update where I remove the whitespace between closing divs.

To fix this you should use a combination of `float` and `clear`

See this example: **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ChubbyNinja/xjL6f/5/)**

**CSS**

```
.text_div
{
    float:left;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    clear:both
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="text_div" style="margin-left: 100px; width: 50px">asadsadfgdgf asdadaa sad
    <br>|</div>
<div class="text_div" style="margin-left: 50px; width: 50px">asadsadsadas asdadaa sad
    <br>|</div>
<div class="text_div" style="margin-left: 50px; width: 50px">asadsadsadas asdadaa sad
    <br>|</div>
<div class="text_div" style="margin-left: 50px; width: 50px">asadsadsadas asdadaa sad
    <br>|</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div style="height: 30px; width: 400px; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
```

Comment: The only problem with this answwer is vertical-align doesn't work with float. Any ideas how to solve that problem?

Comment: I solved it by using display-inline and use a <span> element for the text. text_div have font-size: 0 and span font-size 12.

Comment: Was just trying to work a workaround for you - glad you solved it :-)

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/xjL6f/4/)**

A series of inline-block elements formatted like you normally format HTML will have spaces in between them.

html

```
<div class="text_div" style="margin-left: 100px; width: 50px" >
    asadsadfgdgf asdadaa sad
    <br>
    |
</div><div class="text_div" style="margin-left: 50px; width: 50px" >
    asadsadsadas asdadaa sad
    <br>
    |
</div><div class="text_div" style="margin-left: 50px; width: 50px" >
    asadsadsadas asdadaa sad
    <br>
    |
</div><div class="text_div" style="margin-left: 50px; width: 50px" >
    asadsadsadas asdadaa sad
    <br>
    |
</div><div style="height: 30px; width: 400px; border: 1px solid black;">

</div>
```

[Read here for more info](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a known problem with inline-block displayed elements. The spaces between the inline elements, whic we use to make our markup readable, in thi situtation interpreted as real visible spaces.
There are a few ways to solve this problem (look at [css-tricks post](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/))

For example (I like this one, because it keeps markup readable, but it's discussable):

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="text_div" style="margin-left: 100px; width: 50px">asadsadfgdgf asdadaa sad
        <br>|</div>
    <div class="text_div" style="margin-left: 50px; width: 50px">asadsadsadas asdadaa sad
        <br>|</div>
    <div class="text_div" style="margin-left: 50px; width: 50px">asadsadsadas asdadaa sad
        <br>|</div>
    <div class="text_div" style="margin-left: 50px; width: 50px">asadsadsadas asdadaa sad
        <br>|</div>
</div>
<div style="height: 30px; width: 400px; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
```

css

```
.text_div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size:14px; //now you need to manualy set font-size for your blocks
}

.container {
    font-size: 0px; //this does that trick
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `display:inline-block;` you have to take account on white space. To get rid of that problem you can escape the white space with HTML comments or put the elements right next to each other.

Option 1:

```
<div style='display:inline-block;'>inline block</div><!--
--><div style='display:inline-block;'>inline block</div>
```

Option 2:

```
<div style='display:inline-block;'>
    inline block
</div><div style='display:inline-block;'>
    inline block
</div>
```